# matlab simple matrix manipulation

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

My code is shown below:

```
A = [1 2 3 4];
B = [1;
     2;
     3;
     4];

 s = size(A);
 z = size(B);

for m = 1:s(1,2);


    C= A(1,m)*B(:,1)


    end
end
```

The output was something like this:

```
C =
     4
     8
    12
    16


C =

     1
     2
     3
     4


C =

     2
     4
     6
     8


C =

     3
     6
     9
    12
```

What I wanted to achieve is an output that has the column in one matrix :

```
C =  1 5 10 15
     2 6 11 16
     3 7 12 17
     4 8 13 18
```

(sample values)

when I ran the above codes, it only stores the last column but I want to store all the columns.

Is that possible? I tried doing C(m) but still doesn't work. Please help

Comment: your last C, the expected one, is incorrect, isn't ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab matrices dimension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012140/matlab-matrices-dimension)

Comment: @POW yes the last C was has random numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If dimension are correct you can always use `*` operator

```
>> C = B*A

C =

     1     2     3     4
     2     4     6     8
     3     6     9    12
     4     8    12    16
```